# How to Queue Select Requests When Updating a Single Database Row?

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js, race-condition

I have a scenario where I have a wallet table with two main services: getWallet() and updateWallet(). While I don't encounter any race condition issues during updates, I need the getWallet() service to wait when an update is in progress.

For instance:

Process 1: updateWallet() updates the value from 5 to 7.

Process 2: getWallet() retrieves the old result, which is 5.

I can handle this at the application layer, but I'm wondering if there is a way to queue other select requests while updating only one row in the database.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

db -> postgres

I expected this approach to resolve the race condition problem. Ideally, when updateWallet() is in progress, getWallet() should wait for the update to finish before retrieving the wallet data.

Comment: It all depends on the details. How long could the update possibly take? Normally, a simple update takes only some milliseconds. Then it would not really matter for get() to wait for update to finish. Or are there perhaps yet unmentioned interactions where the result of get() is super important?

Comment: The operations are very quick, but I cannot afford to take this risk. Even the slightest data loss is unacceptable.

Comment: You can use FOR UPDATE.  But if someone can "see" 5 one nanosecond before someone else starts to update it to 7, why is a disaster if they can also see it one nanosecond after that?

Comment: If both processes run independently and randomly, then get() could return 5 because it was called just a moment earlier, so what's the real problem?

Comment: The function getWallet() is intended for internal use within the system rather than for user visibility. For example:

if getWallet() > qty:
    # Perform other service actions.